# Xsd conditional implementation

Tags: java, xml, xsd, schema, xsd-validation

I am trying to validate a pdf files documentation using xsd, where I convert the given pdf to xml and parse it through the schema xsd, and it validates, but lets assume there is a heading and it has 2 subheadings how do I change to xsd schema such that for a particular type of heading it should and must have minimum 2 subheadings of particular text(words/sentences), how do I add conditions to the xsd file for it validate specifically designed documents ?

here is the xsd

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="elements">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="element"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="element">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="pageno"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="level" use="required" type="xs:integer"/>
      <xs:attribute name="title" use="required"/>
      <xs:attribute name="type" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="pageno" type="xs:integer"/>
</xs:schema>
```

and here is the xml I used to generate this xsd:

```
<elements>
<element type ="Introduction" level="1" title="Introduction">
<pageno>4</pageno>
</element>
<element type ="Introduction" level="2" title="Enhancements to the HP CSA vCenter Simple Compute">
<pageno>4</pageno>
</element>
<element type ="System requirements" level="1" title="System requirements">
<pageno>5</pageno>
</element>
<element type ="System requirements" level="2" title="Software components">
<pageno>5</pageno>
</element>
<element type ="Configuration requirements" level="1" title="Configuration requirements">
<pageno>7</pageno>
</element>
<element type ="Configuration requirements" level="2" title="Installing content capsule">
<pageno>7</pageno>
</element>
<element type ="Configuring offerings in HP CSA" level="1" title="Configuring offerings in HP CSA">
<pageno>8</pageno>
</element>
<element type ="Configuring offerings in HP CSA" level="2" title="Configuring subscriber options">
<pageno>8</pageno>
</element>
<element type ="Configuring subscriber options" level="2" title="Adding providers">
<pageno>8</pageno>
</element>
<element type ="Adding providers" level="2" title="Associating resource offerings with providers">
<pageno>9</pageno>
</element>
<element type ="Associating resource offerings with providers" level="2" title="Changing component properties">
<pageno>10</pageno>
</element>
<element type ="Changing component properties" level="2" title="Creating the service offering">
<pageno>12</pageno>
</element>
<element type ="Creating the service offering" level="2" title="Publishing the service offering">
<pageno>13</pageno>
</element>
<element type ="Publishing the service offering" level="3" title="Publishing service offering to a Catalog">
<pageno>13</pageno>
</element>
<element type ="Subscribing to the service" level="1" title="Subscribing to the service">
<pageno>14</pageno>
</element>
<element type ="Subscribing to the service" level="2" title="Canceling a subscription">
<pageno>14</pageno>
</element>
<!-- <element type ="adasdasd" level = "5" title= "dasdsad">
</element> -->
<element type ="Limitations" level="1" title="Limitations">
<pageno>16</pageno>
</element>
<element type ="Appendix A: HP Operations Orchestration flows" level="1" title="Appendix A: HP Operations Orchestration flows">
<pageno>17</pageno>
</element>
<element type ="Appendix B: Integrating with IP Address Management solutions" level="1" title="Appendix B: Integrating with IP Address Management solutions">
<pageno>19</pageno>
</element>
<element type ="Additional resources" level="1" title="Additional resources">
<pageno>20</pageno>
</element>
<element type ="Send Documentation Feedback" level="1" title="Send Documentation Feedback">
<pageno>21</pageno>
</element>
</elements>
```

If you think I am lacking in clarity in question then please let me know I will answer any queries.
Thank you

Comment: How to edit an XSD to add additional conditions ?

Comment: Did you go through the [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/). Others also suggest using an alternate [validation method](http://p2p.wrox.com/xml/46118-xsd-conditional-validation.html)

Comment: Yes thank you i went with XSLT on @barefootliam's suggestion , but its gona take a long day for me to design a proper XSL though.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a Schema type of your own that is a heading that must contain specific text, and use the conditional type assignment feature of XSD 1.1, if your implementation supports it.

A more widely supported approach is to embed Schematron rules in your schema to do what you want.

Remember that if you over-constrain your input the schema may become fragile -- that is, hard to maintain in the event of changes.

Comment: Can you give an example with respect to the above xsd given ? In the sense conditions like each type must have at least two level or each type containing the word "web service" must have minimum 2 levels and have title with name " configuration" and title name "implementation" . Please give an example.